# Plural/singular with certain numbers

Tags: grammatical-number

There's one aspect which is confusing me, especially because of how it's done in my native language which is ukrainian.

So question is how singular and plural forms are used with numbers ending with 1.
- 1 view. No questions asked.
- 11, 211 views. No questions asked either. 
- 0, 2, 5, 13, etc views. No questions here either. 
- 21, 101, 91 **view** or **views**?
In ukrainian, it will be 21 view, 101 view and 91 view. What is right in english?

Comment: Have you Googled {"21 cow" -"21 cows"} and "21 cows", say?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, well no, why would I google something as random as "{"21 cow" -"21 cows"} and "21 cows""

Comment: In the entire history of English not one native speaker has produced "91 view", so while I am closing this as a duplicate, which it is, it really also is general reference and even common knowledge, and as such way too basic for this site.

Comment: It is basic and might be common sense for native speaker, but for me it was confusing especially due to difference with my native language.

Comment: Why do you find 21 confusing but not 22, 23, 24? Ukrainian does not use plural for these, either, but rather what is a remnant of dual from Old East Slavic. Nota bene: I am not a native speaker myself.

Comment: It does use plural for 22, 23 and 24 and so on. Singular is used for 1, and every other number ending with 1 (21, 101, 331 etc) except for anything that ends with 11 (11, 311, 1011 etc).

Comment: Perhaps I misremember and it's just 2, 3, and 4, then. The point still stands that the dual still hasn't expired just yet in Ukrainian, but never so much as existed in English. Anyway, all I meant to say was that there are questions that are too basic for this site, and we don't draw the line between native and non-native OPs, but rather between questions for linguists and questions for any native speaker. For the latter, we have a [dedicated sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's plural for 2,3 and 4 too. It's just that plural form of word used with numbers ending with 2, 3, 4 (22, 33, 44) (excluding 12,13,14) is bit different from plural form of words used with every other number. Didn't see that sister site so I posted here. Nevertheless, I got my answer and for that I thank this community.

Comment: @Flyer There are no examples of the form '21 cow are in the field' but several for '21 cows are . . .' on Google. I chose '21 cow/s' to avoid false positives like '21 View Street'. Perhaps the term 'random' was not a good choice, especially as I added 'say' to my suggestion. Though you were free to choose your own noun, of course. But you showed no sign of research or of checking for previous answers here, which are considered good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 21, 101, 91 **views**.  Always add an 's' if the number is greater than 1.

Comment: Not just greater. Absolutely any number except 1 is plural. Including 0, −1, 0.25.